# Auto reload route every 60 seconds

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to reload route after every 60 seconds. When I have added `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60">` meta tag it refresh the page, but when meta refresh the page the page automatically redirect to the home page.

I need a solution for above issue. I am populating data form JSON so I need to refresh page after every 60 seconds.

```
$http.get('json/dashboard-home.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.campaigns = data;
```

above is a code which I have used to get json data, and below is a method which I have used to access other pages.

```
$scope.tab = $routeParams.tab || 0;
    $scope.views = [
        { src: 'view/dashboard.html' },
        { src: 'view/details.html' },
        { src: 'view/leads.html' }
    ];
```

Comment: You want to refresh the **template** every 60 seconds? Why? Wouldn't you rather want to refresh the *data* every 60 seconds?

Comment: Data is coming form json files, how should I refresh data please suggest.

Comment: In Angular you simply replace the data that is bound to your components. And as long as you do it inside an angular event (or call `$apply()` afterwards), it will automatically update the view for you. That's pretty much the whole point of AngularJS!

Comment: So no need to do anything extra to refresh data. right??

Comment: You're not showing us **any** code, so it's hard to judge if you need to do anything extra. You *need* to periodically request new data (probably using `$timeout` and `$http` or `$resource`).

Comment: I have used $http to get json data in controller. $http.get('json/dashboard-home.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.campaigns = data;

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35992/discussion-between-jquery-finder-and-joachim-sauer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suggest you not to refresh the page every 60 seconds for many reason :

1. It goes against AJAX which is about only load what you need and no more than that.
2. If your idea is about live data, you should use websockets. Everytime you have new json data, then updating it on frontend. This will solve your problem in a correct way.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to refresh the page just to refresh the data - this is the advantage offered by AJAX XHR's over delivering the data with the original response to the client as in plain old PHP, ASP (.net) etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this, but it should be sufficent:

```
var scheduleReload = function() {
  $timeout(function() {
    $http.get('json/dashboard-home.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.campaigns = data;
    });
    scheduleReload();
  }, 60*1000);
};
scheduleReload();
```

Make sure you depend on [the `$timeout` service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24timeout) for this.

Comment: sry friend but $timeout is not working for me, thanks for your help.